# SwiftUI: Animate Text color - foregroundColor()

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've been trying to work on animating various parts of the UI, but it seems as though you can't animate a SwiftUI Text's foregroundColor? I want to switch the color of some text smoothly when a state changes. This works fine if I animate the background color of the Text's surrounding view, but foreground color does not work. Has anyone had any luck animating a change like this? Unsure if this is an Xcode beta bug or it's intended functionality...

```
Text(highlightedText)
    .foregroundColor(color.wrappedValue)
    .animation(.easeInOut)

// Error: Cannot convert value of type 'Text' to closure result type '_'
```

Comment: Quick question? Can you do this in `UIKit`? (I honestly do not know.) I'm guessing there is *very* little you can do in SwiftUI that you cannot do in UIKit at this point in time.

Comment: @dfd quick answer. Yes you can.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini, then I'd say post that UIKit code and have the OP turn it into a `UIViewRepresentable`.

Comment: @dfd for the sake of downvoters, I came with a solution without using `UIKit`.

Comment: I found this answer on reddit which solved it for me: https://www.reddit.com/r/SwiftUI/comments/hxbdns/why_foregroundcolorflag_green_red_do_not_animate/
Basically, adding this:
.foregroundColor(.clear)
    .overlay(Rectangle()
        .foregroundColor(color.wrappedValue)
        .mask(Text(highlightedText))
    )

Answer (score 55, accepted):

There is a much easier way, borrowing from Apple's "Animating Views and Transitions" tutorial code. The instantiation of GraphCapsule in HikeGraph demonstrates this.

While `foregroundColor` cannot be animated, `colorMultiply` can. Set the foreground color to white and use colorMultiply to set the actual color you want. To animate from red to blue:

```
struct AnimateDemo: View {
    @State private var color = Color.red

    var body: some View {
        Text("Animate Me!")
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .colorMultiply(self.color)
            .onTapGesture {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1)) {
                    self.color = Color.blue
                }
        }
    }
}

struct AnimateDemo_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AnimateDemo()
    }
}
```

Comment: so I can't actually find the reference in the Apple tutorial https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/animating-views-and-transitions#Add-Animations-to-Individual-Views but this works like a charm, thank you

Comment: This will break characters such as emoji because they turn into a flat color. I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/57836412/2966461 to be a more robust solution

Answer (score 9):

[image]

Color property of `Text` is not animatable in `SwiftUI` or `UIKit`. **BUT YOU CAN** achieve the result you need like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var highlighted = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
            // Highlighted State
            Text("Text To Change Color")
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .opacity(highlighted ? 1 : 0)

            // Normal State
            Text("Text To Change Color")
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .opacity(highlighted ? 0 : 1)
            }
            Button("Change") {
                withAnimation(.easeIn) {
                    self.highlighted.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can encapsulate this functionality in a custom `View` and use it anywhere you like.

Comment: Nice answer! Hopefully in a future version of SwiftUI you can do it directly.

Answer (score 7):

There is a nice protocol in SwiftUI that let you animate anything. Even things that are not animatable! (such as the text color). The protocol is called AnimatableModifier.

If you would like to learn more about it, I wrote a full article explaining how this works: https://swiftui-lab.com/swiftui-animations-part3/

Here's an example on how you can accomplish such a view:

```swift
AnimatableColorText(from: UIColor.systemRed, to: UIColor.systemGreen, pct: flag ? 1 : 0) {
    Text("Hello World").font(.largeTitle)
}.onTapGesture {
    withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 2.0)) {
      self.flag.toggle()
    }
}
```

And the implementation:

```swift
struct AnimatableColorText: View {
    let from: UIColor
    let to: UIColor
    let pct: CGFloat
    let text: () -> Text

    var body: some View {
        let textView = text()

        // This should be enough, but there is a bug, so we implement a workaround
        // AnimatableColorTextModifier(from: from, to: to, pct: pct, text: textView)

        // This is the workaround
        return textView.foregroundColor(Color.clear)
            .overlay(Color.clear.modifier(AnimatableColorTextModifier(from: from, to: to, pct: pct, text: textView)))
    }

    struct AnimatableColorTextModifier: AnimatableModifier {
        let from: UIColor
        let to: UIColor
        var pct: CGFloat
        let text: Text

        var animatableData: CGFloat {
            get { pct }
            set { pct = newValue }
        }

        func body(content: Content) -> some View {
            return text.foregroundColor(colorMixer(c1: from, c2: to, pct: pct))
        }

        // This is a very basic implementation of a color interpolation
        // between two values.
        func colorMixer(c1: UIColor, c2: UIColor, pct: CGFloat) -> Color {
            guard let cc1 = c1.cgColor.components else { return Color(c1) }
            guard let cc2 = c2.cgColor.components else { return Color(c1) }

            let r = (cc1[0] + (cc2[0] - cc1[0]) * pct)
            let g = (cc1[1] + (cc2[1] - cc1[1]) * pct)
            let b = (cc1[2] + (cc2[2] - cc1[2]) * pct)

            return Color(red: Double(r), green: Double(g), blue: Double(b))
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Tried the code - very useful. What I need is the text to start in blue, then transitions to red, stays 2 secs and then goes back to blue color.

Comment: @thstart If you need to pause between both animations, you may use two separate animations and start the second one inside `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(4)) { ... }`