# Animating Image color with foregroundColor doesn't actually animate interactively

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying out some animation stuffs from Apple's SwiftUI tutorials. The section [Add Animations to Individual Views](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/animating-views-and-transitions#add-animations-to-individual-views) says:

> A view’s color, opacity, rotation, size, and other properties are all animatable.

But when I tried animating the Image color with `foregroundColor(_:)` modifier by means of toggling the value of the `State` property, it doesn't seem to be actually animating. For the sake of the investigation, I added a duration for the animation to be longer.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var isFavorite = false

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 5)) { self.isFavorite.toggle() }
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(self.isFavorite ? .orange : .gray)
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(self.isFavorite ? 360 : 0))
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, the color change `orange <<->> gray` happens immediately. However the rotation effect does respect the animation and it's interactive too.

---

**Essentially not a duplicate:**

I came across a similar question [SwiftUI: Animate Text color - foregroundColor()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57832439/swiftui-animate-text-color-foregroundcolor) but that is about `Text` component. So I assume it's not a direct duplicate.

---

And there is not enough documentation in the developer site about [foregroundColor(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/image/3269646-foregroundcolor), so I assume the quote in the tutorials should be the source of truth.

So my question is whether it is a bug or an intentional behavior?

Comment: Have a look at this : https://swiftui-lab.com/swiftui-animations-part3/
AnimatableModifier might be the solution for this...